# Create expression tree for to get property value

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I've got a method that walks up through an expression tree building a '.' delimited string of property names

```
public static string GetPropertyNameFor<TSource, TProperty>(Expression<Func<TSource, TProperty>> propertyLambda, bool fullyQualified)
{
       // if fullyQualified return Bar.BoolProp1
       // else return BoolProp1
}
```

Usage:

```
var propName = GetPropertNameFor<Foo, bool>(foo=>foo.Bar.BoolProp1);
```

But what I need to do now is call the method at run time. I have the type and a the PropertyInfo hierarchy. Presumably I need to create an override that access a type as another arg and create an expression tree to pass in to properyLambda.

is that correct? all the example of expression tree look hugely complicated; any advice appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Use `expression.Compile()`. It gives you the method which represents the lambda expression.

Comment: thanks for reply, but I already have method to get the string representation, i want to get from string to Expression.

Comment: @sambomartin Oh, sorry! Editing.